# 'await' has no effect on the type of this expression when using await inside an if block

Tags: javascript, typescript

In my code I have an array of user names. I'm trying to go through each name, check whether the user exist in the database and create the user. The problem is, my linter is saying `'await' has no effect on the type of this expression` in the places I have marked:

```js
await Promise.all(
  userNames.map(async userName => {
    const user = await users.findOne({ name: userNames });

    if (!user)
      await users.create({ // Linter marks this bracket (Not the curly bracket)
        name: userName,
      }); // And this end bracket
  }),
);
```

My editor suggests something like this:

```js
  if (user) {
    return;
  }
  await users.create({
    name: userName,
  });
```

Flipping the if else. Any idea why?

Comment: try adding return before await
`if (!user)
      return await users.create({ // Linter marks this bracket (Not the curly bracket)
        name: userName,
      }); // And this end bracket`

Comment: what does `users.create` return?

Comment: @georg It's supposed to create a user in the database and return that user object. But at this moment, I do not need the returned object.

Comment: @THpubs just curious, what editor/linter are you using that suggests stuff like that? And I think that even though users.create didn't have a promise, the editor was suggesting that for clarity because it does that exact same thing both ways.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The issue was, `users.create` is not a promise to be awaited! One good way to find this is to click on <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>click</kbd> on the method and check it's type definitions.

Answer (score 2):

I received same warning/error

Resolved: My await was waiting for a non-async method

Just made the 'waited for' function async and it works.

```
try{ 
await this.waited_for_function() //ERROR ts(80007) 'await' has no effect on this type of expression
this.function_runs_after_waiting()
 } 
catch(error){console.log(`error:${error.message}`)
```

from:

```
waited_for_function(){ 
  console.log(`creates warning above`}
```

to:

```
async waited_for_function(){
  console.log(`good to go!`}
```