# Promise is not executing correclty?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I want to run `_this.install()` once promise is completed it seems not working any idea what would be better approach ?

main.js

```
async function gitSetUp(path, obj) {
  const _this = obj
  let myFirstPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    gitclass.cloneHttps(_this.props.appName)
    setTimeout( function() {
      resolve("Success!")  // Yay! Everything went well!
    }, 250) 
  }) 
  myFirstPromise.then(function(res){
    process.chdir(`${process.cwd()}/${_this.props.appName}`);
    _this.install();
  })

}
```

GitClass Code

I minimize the code may be some variables are not mapped correclty just to understand the promise logic

```
class GitClass {

    cloneHttps(appName) {

        nodegit.Clone.clone(url)
            .then(function(repo) {
                console.log(`Repo ${repo} cloned.`);
                const data = {
                    cloneOptions: cloneOptions,
                    dir: DIR
                }
                return data;
            }).then(function(data) {
                return openRepo(data.dir, data.cloneOptions, appName);
            })
            .catch(function(err) {
                console.log(err);
            });

    }
}

function openRepo(dir, cloneOptions, appName) {

    //getMostRecent master branch commit
    const getMostRecentCommit = function(repository) {
        return repository.getBranchCommit('master').then(function(commit) {
            repoData.commit = commit;
            return repoData;
        });
    };
    // create new branch
    const createBranch = function(data) {
        return data.repo.createBranch(data.branchName, data.commit, 1).then(function(res) {
            data.res = res;
            return data
        });
    }

    // call main node function for promise chaining
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        nodegit.Repository.open(dir)
            .then(getMostRecentCommit)
            .then(createBranch)
            .then(function(res) {
                console.log("Promise Results", res);
                resolve(res);
            })
            .catch(function(err) {
                console.log("ERRR>>>>>>>", err);
            });
    })

}
```

Comment: do you get any errors?

Comment: @losif gitClass.cloneHttps is creating new directory where install job will be done and install is running before the git operations that is causing tons of error

Comment: What makes you suspect that the git operation will finish in 250 milliseconds?

Comment: does gitclass.cloneHttps return a Promise?

Comment: yes it is returning a promise

Comment: ok Check my answer.

Comment: @Fraddy added Gitclass code to understand the promise

Answer (score 0):

Is something like this works ?

```js
async function gitSetUp(path, obj) {
    await gitclass.cloneHttps(obj.props.appName)
    process.chdir(`${process.cwd()}/${obj.props.appName}`);
    obj.install();
}
```

I'm not sure your promise is really needed.
And the `const _this = obj` is not necessary :)

If you want to clone a repo something like this should work

```js
https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback

async function gitSetUp(path, obj) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
   exec(`git clone ${obj.appName}`, null, function() {
    obj.install();
    resolve()
  });
}
```

Comment: 'await' has no effect on the type of this expression.ts(80007)

Comment: hum ok, it's probably a sync function, so you just don't need to use promise here.

Comment: try the `child_process.exec` way ?

Comment: @hussain, you state that `gitclass.cloneHttps` returns a promise. But if you get this error, that means it does not return a promise. Can you clarify?

Comment: @trincot added Gitclass code to understand the promise

Comment: @hussain, The problem is that that `cloneHttps` function does not return anything. It should *return* the promise it works with (`return nodegit.Clone.clone.......`)

Answer (score 0):

If `gitclass.cloneHttps` function returns a Promise then you do not require `myFirstPromise`. Try below snippet.

```
async function gitSetUp(path, obj) {
  const _this = obj;

  try {
    await gitclass.cloneHttps(_this.props.appName);
  } catch (error) {
    throw error;
  }

  process.chdir(`${process.cwd()}/${_this.props.appName}`);
  _this.install();
}
```

**Edited:**
If you are getting `'await' has no effect on the type of this expression.ts(80007)` then check link ['await' has no effect on the type of this expression when using await inside an if block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59114874/await-has-no-effect-on-the-type-of-this-expression-when-using-await-inside-an)

**Edited:**
@Hussain cloneHttps method is not returning Promise.

Replace `nodegit.Clone.clone(url)` by `return nodegit.Clone.clone(url)`

And also I think there is a issue with first then callback `nodegit.Clone.clone(url)` ( does not return Promise )

Comment: for some reason await is showing error `'await' has no effect on the type of this expression.ts(80007)`